# Is my gateway a fixed or a dynamic IP?

Tags: networking, nat, azure

I have some virtual machines under my control with Azure, some of them have public IP and some of them don't.

In regards to the one that don't: I can see that they still have internet outbound (not inbound) access via NAT, connecting to some virtual gateway 10.0.0.1.

So my question is: will the public IP assigned to this NAT configuration be dynamic, or static, for my server that doesn't have public IP address?

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly is the nat configured? What is the static public ip address of the gateway?

Comment: it starts with 13.76.142.__

Comment: how can I answer the question `how is the nat configured?`? I didn't configure it, it came like that with Azure

Comment: So, if you have a fixed static ip, then it is static.  You can also use traceroute command to see how the outgoing traffic flows. Or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: You can delete the comment with ip, it is not required. I only wanted to know if you have a static or a dynamic ip configured.

Answer (score 0):

You choose if you want it to be static or dynamic when you create a public IP for your instance. At any moment, you can also change the configuration.

If you are using ARM, you should see the IP address resource in the list. Click on it and select Configuration. Just change it to your desired state.

[image]

This also applies to the private IP address. By default it's dynamic and if you want to change it, just go to your network card resource configuration and change the IP address to static.

Update: I see that you're not talking about your own virtual machines. In this case, you have no control over the default gateway of the Virtual Network. There's no way to change if it's static or dynamic nor information regarding if the Public IP is static and you shouldn't count on it.

Comment: I guess you can delete your whole answer except for the last paragraph, really